# How to get prime numbers between 1000-2000 in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is the code I have

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
ACOUNTER INTEGER;
IS_PRIME INTEGER;
BEGIN
IS_PRIME := 1;
FOR NUM IN 1000..2000 LOOP
    FOR D IN 2..NUM-1 LOOP
        IF MOD(NUM,D) = 0 THEN
        IS_PRIME := 0;
        END IF;
      END LOOP; 
END LOOP;

IF IS_PRIME = 1 THEN
ACOUNTER := ACOUNTER +1;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: ' || ACOUNTER);
END;
```

I get an error:

> Error starting at line : 2 in command - Error report - ORA-06550: line
>   18, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one
>   of the following:
>
> if
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:
>       END;

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I was wondering what syntax error I have. It looks like the logic makes sense to me.

Comment: You don't terminate each line of SQL with `;`.  That's one problem.

Comment: You're missing an end-if for a start; presumably you have `end;` after the code you showed?

Comment: Editing your question to fix the error the question was about isn't very helpful to anyone coming along later. Adding the `END;` is OK as you already had that really, but adding the missing `END IF` makes the answers look invalid. Removing the error message wasn't helpful either, though I see that wasn't you.

Comment: OP has edited the question so that the original problem has disappeared. Sigh.

Comment: Sorry I'll put my original code up there again.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this programmatically? The number of primes in the range of 1000-2000 will number far fewer than 1000. Pre-calculate them (grab them off the internet somewhere). If you need them for other calculations, they can just be a list in Oracle, considering that Oracle queries allow up to 1000 items in a list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is homework, since the OP said in a comment on an answer that he was taught this today...

Comment: As an aside, when implementing this in PL/SQL, it would be better to make `IS_PRIME` a `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have an `END IF`; given the line number the error is reported on, you have an `END;` after what you've shown, so the last few lines are:

```
...
IF IS_PRIME = 1 THEN
ACOUNTER := ACOUNTER +1;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: ' || ACOUNTER);
END;
/
```

When the compiler sees that `END;` it's expecting the preceding `IF` to be closed, so it throws an exception when it see the `;`. Just add an `END IF` after the prime check:

```
...
    IF IS_PRIME = 1 THEN
        ACOUNTER := ACOUNTER +1;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: ' || ACOUNTER);
END;
/
```

Consistent indentation makes this sort of this more obvious and easier to track down.

You're also setting and checking your flag in the wrong place - both should be inside the first loop - and you have to initialise your counter before you start, as it will default to null:

```
DECLARE
    ACOUNTER INTEGER := 0;
    IS_PRIME INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR NUM IN 1000..2000 LOOP
        IS_PRIME := 1;
        FOR D IN 2..NUM-1 LOOP
            IF MOD(NUM,D) = 0 THEN
                IS_PRIME := 0;
            END IF;
        END LOOP; 

        IF IS_PRIME = 1 THEN
            ACOUNTER := ACOUNTER +1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: ' || ACOUNTER);
END;
/

anonymous block completed
THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: 135
```

See @ruudvan's comments about your algorithm too though; that version gets the same answer 135, but more efficiently (in a tenth of the time on my system; about 0.06 seconds versus 0.60 with this simpler approach).

Comment: I've went ahead and tried the end if and I get more error codes

Comment: @NgocPhan - I can't guess what errors you got, or why; just adding the `END IF` compiles and runs, though it gets the wrong result. I've added an amended block too, moving the logic around, which gets an answer now. No idea what you are doing differently to get errors.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I see what I did wrong with the logic.

Comment: See my comment about the incorrect results. Nevermind, I think you got it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `END IF` for this IF - `IF IS_PRIME = 1 THEN`

There is no `END;` for the complete `BEGIN...END` block.

The error tells you right there what action you have to take -

> Action: END;

which usually means that you have to put the END keyword somewhere.

Some suggestions about the algorithm to find a prime number -

1. When checking for a prime number, you don't have to loop until num-1. Looping until square-root(num) will work fine. [Proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Testing_primality_and_integer_factorization)
2. When you find a number that is not prime, exit the loop. No need to check for any further divisors for that number.

EDIT: Mistakes in your logic which will give you incorrect results -

1. Inside the first loop, re-initialize the variable IS_PRIME to 1.
2. The counter increment should happen inside the first loop.

This is the correct program -

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
   ACOUNTER   INTEGER;
   IS_PRIME   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   ACOUNTER   := 0;
   IS_PRIME   := 1;

   FOR NUM IN 1000 .. 2000
   LOOP
      IS_PRIME   := 1;

      FOR D IN 2 .. SQRT (num)
      LOOP
         IF MOD (NUM, D) = 0
         THEN
            IS_PRIME   := 0;
            EXIT;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      IF IS_PRIME = 1
      THEN
         ACOUNTER   := ACOUNTER + 1;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
      'THE # OF PRIME NUMBERS BETWEEN 1000-2000 ARE: ' || ACOUNTER);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This is the way that I was taught earlier today on how to check for the prime number. I will look into the sqaure-root method.

Comment: The reason the square root method works is that if a number is not prime, at least one of its factors will be less than or equal its own square root.

Answer (score 1):

Alex Poole has addressed the actual issues with your code. However, as with many problems, if you're going to solve this question in the database, you'd probably be better off using SQL. In that spirit, a SQL solution to this problem follows.

```
WITH pc AS
        (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT     LEVEL AS numbers
                 FROM       DUAL
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2000)
         WHERE  (numbers = 2 OR MOD (numbers, 2) <> 0) AND numbers <> 1)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT numbers FROM pc
        MINUS
        SELECT pc1.numbers
        FROM   pc pc1
               JOIN pc pc2
                  ON     pc2.numbers <= CEIL (SQRT (pc1.numbers))
                     AND MOD (pc1.numbers, pc2.numbers) = 0)
WHERE  numbers BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

The `connect by` produces all numbers between 1 and 2000. Using well accepted rules, we can eliminate all even numbers above two and only test the modulus for each number for values below the square root of the number.

Technically, this solution generates every prime between 2 and 2000, then filters out everything under 2000. Since in produces a complete result in under a second, the extra work is irrelevant.

Comment: Depending on the use case this could in fact be better, and it is certainly a well thought out solution. However, the PL/SQL performs better; extending the range to 1..10000, the PL/SQL still runs sub-second. When I extended this query, however, took over 12 second to return.

Comment: @HepC: It appears to depend on the PL/SQL solution. For 1...10,000, Alex Poole's answer takes 19 seconds and ruudvan's answer takes <1 second, compared to 10 seconds for my SQL answer (in my environment, clearly). The ability to exit as soon as a single divisor is found is definitely an advantage to the PL/SQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Always is a better alternative if possible to use just SQL instead of PLSQL

```
WITH A AS (
 SELECT LEVEL AS L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2000
)
SELECT 
LISTAGG(L,', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY L)
FROM 
    (
        SELECT L FROM A MAIN
        WHERE L >= 1000 AND
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM A SUB
            WHERE 
            MAIN.L>SUB.L
            AND MOD(MAIN.L,L)=0
            AND SUB.L>1
        )
        AND L<>1
    );
```